# How to increase or decrease value of an object parameter in an array in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist

I am trying to adjust (increase and decrease) the value of an object parameter contained in an array.
The code structure is basically something like this:

```
data Class MyData (val id:String, var count:Int)

 private val listItems = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<MyData>>()

fun increaseItemCount(id:String) {
     listItems.value?.find { item ->
         item.id == id }?.count?.plus(1) }
```

I tried using the *increaseItemCount* function above but couldn't get it to work.
Any idea on how I can implement this?

Comment: How do you determine it’s not working? Are you aware the LiveData will not emit a new value when you merely change something it is indirectly pointing to? It will only fire observer callbacks if its `value` is directly changed.

Comment: I placed break points at the end of the function and evaluated the value of count after it was called. There was no increament. As for the LiveData update, how do you suggest I go about it?

Comment: You can call `liveData.value = liveData.value` after changing the indirect value to force it to notify observers. If this looks stupid, it’s because you’re not really supposed to use mutable classes with LiveData in the first place. It can be really error prone depending on how you’re using it in the observer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is basically that you increment the value of `count` - and then throw it away. `Int.plus(...)` is nothing else than `+` between integers. So, you are calculating `count + 1` but you are not using the result.

If you intend to increment the value of `count` and store that value in the variable `count`, you can alter your function in the following way:

```
fun increaseItemCount(id:String) {
    listItems.value?.find { item -> item.id == id }?.let { it.count += 1 } 
}
```

As @cactustictacs pointed out, this will update the list inside the `LiveData`, but no observers will be notified, since the `LiveData` does not know of any change that has been made inside the `value`.
In order to notify the `LiveData` of a change, its `setValue` function has to be called after the change:

```
fun increaseItemCount(id:String) = listItems.run {
    value?.find { it.id == id }?.let { it.count += 1 }
    value = value
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks. I've marked it as a solution to my initial question but I'm afraid I might have developed any issue: how to update the value in the LiveData List.

Comment: @MrBE this does update the list held in your ``LiveData`` - but the LiveData has no idea anything's changed inside the object it holds, so it won't notify observers that there's an update. You need to call ``setValue`` with the list again

Comment: @cactustictacs could you please elaborate?

Comment: @MrBE get the list from listItems, do your find/count update on it, call ``listItems.setValue(theListYouJustModified)``. Instead of trying to do it all as a one-liner, maybe do ``val theList = listItems.value`` so you can work with it easily

Comment: @cactustictacs Nice! I added that information to the answer.